# React Native navigation causes resetting of context

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am Developing a React-Native app, using the https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/ for navigating between screens. Each screen is a separate component (lets say A and B). To share data between screens I have used the React Context API. Whenever I manipulate some state change in the context, and then navigate to another screen that also share the same context, the provided context value is reset. I believe that it has to do with unmounting the screens when changing (navigating) between screens and that would cause it to reset to the initial value.

The structure (navigation stack):

```
<... some components>

<Wrapping for component A>
  <Context Provider>
    <Component A>
  </Context Provider>
</Wrapping for component A>

..
<some other components>
..

<Wrapping for component B>
  <Context Provider>
    <Component B>
  </Context Provider>
</Wrapping for component B>
```

How would you keep state between swapping screens? These screens are on very different ends of the "tree structure" so wrapping the entire app with context is my last solution, any advice?

Comment: Maybe add condition to initial state with `props.context || initialContext` something like this and parse context when you navigate to next page?

Comment: @高鵬翔, Thanks for answering! So you would send the context with props when changing screen? I kind of tried this, and it will most likely solve it,  but then what's the point of having context if you end up "propsing" it around anyway? The reason I started using context was to not pass props through nested components!

Comment: I haven't use that before, so I just answer what I think may be worked... If the data should be shared, I may send by props or state to keep it..  But it looks may have some like state or other to keep data if it create so complicated. and you may take data from something like redux or global state in this structure?